# CollectionType grouped by value in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I am pretty new to symfony and i'm stuck on something.

I have a form where i want to edit **Products** for a **UserCart**.
Each product has a ProductType.

I created a CollectionType of Products in my UserCartType to edit the products.

In my twig, i am currently iterating my CollectionType field to display the products

```
{% for product in form.products %}
    {{ form_row(product) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The result is good, but what i want is group my products in my twig by their ProductType.

It would look like this for example:

```
Cookies
    Cookie1
    Cookie2
Yogourt
   Yogourt1
   Yogourt2
   Yogourt
```

Where Cookies and Yogourt are ProductTypes you could find in the collection list of product

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to make it once, I guess better to sort it with php and
  use [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)
- Second way to do it is [Twig Extension](http://Second%20way%20to%20make%20it%20is)
- The third way is [Twig Macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I started  with a DTO that represent my data hierarchy.
ProductEditDTO that contain the ProductType and Products associated with it.
I then created a CollectionType of ProductEditDTO, like this i can easily iterate over each DTO.
Plus, i need custom options depending the ProductType.
I was watching over Data Transformer but didnt really know how to implement it for my use case :/